# Notation used to denote the unit $\rm mm^3$

Tags: conventions, notation, si-units, metrology

For example, to denote the volume of a cube with the sides $1mm$ we write $1mm^3$. But I think it should be written as $1 (mm)^3$ because the prefix $m$ denote the factor $10^{-3}$ hence $$[1mm^3=10^{-3}m^3]\quad\neq\quad [1(mm)^3=10^{-9}m^3]$$ Isn't $1 mm^3$ an abuse of notation or I'm missing something?

Comment: You can define notation however you want, but the usual way is more convenient. In your way, almost every expression would have to have tons of parentheses.

Comment: "But wasn't I taught in school that exponents come before multiplication?" Well, that's also a convention too. In school algebra, we do it that way, because it tends to reduce the number of parentheses you need. (Otherwise, say, $2x^2 = 1$ would have to be written as $2(x^2) = 1$.) For units, we do it this other way, also to reduce the number of parentheses. You can use any rule you want as long as it's clear from context.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks for the very good explanation! It is clear now.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question to me (because notation and convention _is_ important), and I don't know the answer to this. However, I should say that kilograms $\text{kg}$ is treated as its own unit (so $\text{kg}^{3} = (\text{kg})^{3}\ne \text{k}(\text{g})^{3}$) from what I've seen. @knzhou's comments seem very apt here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prefix of a unit symbol is conventionally understood to bind more tightly than an exponent, so the symbol $\mathrm{mm}^3$ is defined to be $(\mathrm{mm})^3$ rather than $\mathrm m (\mathrm m^3)$.

See section 6.2.3 of the NIST [Guide for the Use of the International System of Units](https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/pdf/sp811.pdf):

> The grouping formed by a prefix symbol attached to a unit symbol constitutes a new inseparable
> symbol (forming a multiple or submultiple of the unit concerned) which can be raised to a positive or
> negative power and which can be combined with other unit symbols to form compound unit symbols.